# Compress a string in php not match

Tags: php, compression

I tried to compress a string in php by this code

```
$data = base64_encode( gzcompress(gzdeflate('compress me')));
```

I want the result like this site http://www.txtwizard.net/compression (expected result is `eJxLzs8tKEotLlbITQUAGx0EXw==` with string `compress me`)
but my code returned `eJzzPndeV8NLVy/shC8rAwAj8QRT`.

Any ideas how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you want come from the following code. It only use [`gzcompress()`](https://secure.php.net/gzcompress):

```
echo base64_encode(gzcompress('compress me'));
```

Outputs:

```
eJxLzs8tKEotLlbITQUAGx0EXw==
```

Example [online](https://3v4l.org/HJPtq).

Comment: Thanks ! You save my day! I use compress code in https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-http-encoding.php so get stuck with it !!!